# Converting grayscale video to binary for code generation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, simulink, matlab-cvst

this is my problem: recently I learned something about code generation from Simulink model by `Simulink Coder`. The model includes a `MATLAB Function` block that converts from gray-scale video signal to binary using:

**EDIT:**
    Binary = im2bw(inputVideo, level);

because, for my application, I noticed that it is more accurate than `Autothreshold` block (I do not why), but `Simulink Coder` does not support `im2bw` function (like you can see here http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/simulink/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--categorical-list.html#bsl0arh-1). So, I would try to create an `outputVideo` using:

```
Binary = false(size(inputVideo)); % to inizialize
Binary(inputVideo>=threshold)==true;
```

...but when I do that with an grayscale image, `outbinary` image is a full-black image. Is there a way to perform this conversion without using `Autothreshold` block or `im2bw` function ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
Binary(inputVideo>=threshold)==true;
```

Here you are comparing `Binary(inputVideo>=threshold)` with `true`. Correct:

```
Binary(inputVideo>=threshold)=true;
```

Comment: I edited above replacing threshold with level (from MATLAB help). In my case it was 0.15. How can I find the threshold value in your code?

Comment: The problem is the '==' which compares, you need a '=' to assign.

Comment: Ok, it works but now how can I find a threshold for a im2bw level I of 0.15 (with a 'single' as datatype)? In the im2bw it was between 0 and 1.

Comment: I have never seen an image of type single, how do you get such an image? Should be range 0...1 as well.

Comment: yes, it is between 0 and 1 like double. It's a matlab datatype format.

Comment: Then your `threshold` and `level` is the same value.